Creating telegram bot API wrapper in Kotlin with Coroutines
I need a suggestion regarding the architecture of the telegram bot API wrapper. So basically I need a way to handle updates efficiently. I have checked how kotlin-telgram-bot does it. And it has a Courotine dispatcher on a single thread Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher(). Handling its update as follows:
private val scope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(coroutineDispatcher)

@Volatile private var job: Job? = null

internal fun startCheckingUpdates() {
    job?.cancel()
    job = scope.launch { checkQueueUpdates() }
}

private suspend fun checkQueueUpdates() {
    while (true) {
        when (val item = updatesChannel.receive()) {
            is Update -> handleUpdate(item)
            is TelegramError -> handleError(item)
            else -> Unit
        }
        yield()
    }
}


Is it an effective way to handle updates?
Can I use a coroutine dispatcher that works on several threads?

So if you have a recommendation for the best design of update handling I would appreciate it.

Making the job variable @Volatile is probably an effort to make startCheckingUpdates thread safe. But two threads calling that method simultaneously can still cause trouble. Thread A cancels job1, writes job2 to the field; thread B also cancels job1, writes job3 to the field. Then job2 is not tracked and won't be cancelled.

You will usually want to benefit from using structured concurrency. That means that you don't create coroutine scopes individually on the class level, instead you define one at an application level or use one that is provided by the UI framework when that is the entry point to your application. All other coroutines and scopes should be launched in some way (directly or indirectly) with the root scope as its parent. This way you can always cancel a scope and all its children including their coroutines when some functionality isn't used any more.
Moreover, suspend functions and coroutines should define for themselves which dispatcher they want to use for which parts of their code. After all, they know best what they are about to do and which dispatcher would be the most appropriate. New coroutines can be supplied a context parameter when launched, suspend functions can use withContext to switch the dispatcher.
There are some predefined dispatchers you could use, but best practice is to have the dispatcher supplied via a parameter of the enclosing class, for example, so you can easily switch it out for your unit tests. Actively switching to that dispatcher, however, should still do the coroutine or the suspend function itself.
I cannot tell if the given dispatcher is appropriate without any knowledge about what that function actually does. But since it seems to form an event loop of some kind and doesn't launch any new coroutines (as far as I can tell), it would be pointless to assign it to a dispatcher with multiple threads. It wouldn't hurt, but it also wouldn't help because everything in that suspend function is executed synchronously, one after another.
When updatesChannel is a kotlinx.coroutines.channels.Channel then this kind of suspending loop is an idiomatic way to react to incoming events. Multiple threads would only be helpful if that one thread cannot keep up with handling the events as they come in. Since I suspect that there is some network IO involved for the events I would expect that handleUpdate can easily finish handling one event before the next one arrives.
